# How to drag and drop instances of a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip (star) in my library and i set it's class linkage name  "star". Then i use my code to call it on stage.I want to create multiple instances of star in the same position and all be draggable but unfortunately I manage to create two instances of that movieclip and only one is draggable.I need some help with my code. Thank you.

```
var stars:Array =  [];
var star:Star = new Star();
this.addChild(star);
stars.push(star);
star.x=550;
star.y=490;

for(var i=0; i<stars.length; ++i)
 {
   trace(stars);
   star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
   star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);

}

function clickToDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.startDrag();
    var star:Star = new Star();
    this.addChild(star);
    stars.push(star);
    star.x=550;
    star.y=490;
}

function releaseToDrop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
    if (star.hitTestObject(target))

 {
    trace("Collision detected!");
   e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
    }
 else
  {
    trace("No collision.");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/DkVke/

Answer (score 0):

You are adding listener to only one star. Add it to all stars like so,

```
var totalStars:int = 20;

for(var i=0; i<totalStars; i++)
{       
   var star:Star = new Star();
   this.addChild(star);
   star.x=550;
   star.y=490;

   star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
   star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);

   stars.push(star); 
}
```